# Do I inherit Promise class and use it like this way correct?

Tags: javascript

My background is C#. So, when I come to Javascript, I want to make it be friendly with C# based on the syntax. So, I'm writing this small plugin:

```js
(function (global) {
    'use strict';

    //require('babel-polyfill');
    
    let Task = (function () {
        let __task__ = Symbol('Task'),
            __data = {};

        __data.then = function (...args) {
            if (args.length) {
                let run = this[__task__]['run'];

                this[__task__]['TResult'] = run();

                return Promise.resolve(this[__task__]['action']).then(args[0], args[1]);
            }
        };   
        __data.Run = function (...args) {
            if (args.length) {
                let func = args[0];

                return new Task(func);
            }
        };
        __data.Wait = function (...args) {
            let run = this[__task__]['run'];

            this[__task__]['TResult'] = run();

            return this;
        };
        
        class Task extends Promise {
            constructor(action) {
                let run = null;

                super((resolve, reject) => run = () => action(resolve, reject));

                this[__task__] = {
                    action: action,
                    run: run
                };
            }
            set then(value) {
                return __data.then;
            }
            get then() {
                return (...args) => __data.then.call(this, ...args);
            }
            set Result(result) {
                return this[__task__]['TResult'] || undefined;
            }
            get Result() {
                return this[__task__]['TResult'] || undefined;
            }
            static set Run(value) {
                return __data.Run;
            }
            static get Run() {
                return (...args) => __data.Run.call(this, ...args);
            }
            set Wait(value) {
                return __data.Wait;
            }
            get Wait() {
                return (...args) => __data.Wait.call(this, ...args);
            }
        }
        return Task;
    }());

    //module.exports = Task;
    global.Task = Task;
}(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this));

(async () => {
    let $log = window.$log || console.log;

    let func = function () {
        $log('foo');

        return 'bar';
    };

    let task = Task.Run(() => func());

    for (let i of [1, 2, 3]) {
        $log(`start... [${i}]`);

        await task;

        $log('result:', task.Result);

        $log('done.');

        $log('==========');
    }

    $log('using "Wait" method:');

    task = Task.Run(() => func());

    $log('start...');

    task.Wait();

    $log('result:', task.Result);
    $log('done.');
})();
```

Let me compare them first:

C# syntax:

```
    static Task<string> func()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("foo");

        return Task.FromResult<string>("bar");
    }
    
    static async Task Main()
    {
        Task<string> task = Task.Run(() => func());

        foreach (int i in new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 })
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"start...[{i}]");

            await task;

            Console.WriteLine($"Result: {task.Result}");
            Console.WriteLine("done.");
            Console.WriteLine("==========");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("using \"Wait\" method:");

        task = Task.Run(() => func());

        Console.WriteLine("start...");
    
        task.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine($"Result: {task.Result}");
        Console.WriteLine("done.");
    }
```

JS syntax:

```
(async () => {
    let $log = window.$log || console.log;

    let func = function () {
        $log('foo');

        return 'bar';
    };

    let task = Task.Run(() => func());

    for (let i of [1, 2, 3]) {
        $log('start...');

        await task;

        $log('result:', task.Result);

        $log('done.');

        $log('==========');
    }

    $log('using "Wait" method:');

    task = Task.Run(() => func());

    $log('start...');

    task.Wait();

    $log('result:', task.Result);
    $log('done.');
})();
```

And the main point which makes this plugin works:

```
constructor(action) {
    let run = null;

    super((resolve, reject) => run = () => action(resolve, reject));

    this[__task__] = {
        action: action,
        run: run
    };
}

__data.then = function (...args) {
    if (args.length) {
        let run = this[__task__]['run'];

        this[__task__]['TResult'] = run();

        return Promise.resolve(this[__task__]['action']).then(args[0], args[1]);
    }
};
```

I've use `run` as a variable to store the content of the promise and use it everytime `await` calls.

That's the difference with another examples I've searched on Google for `extends promise`:

```
class AngularPromise extends Promise {
    constructor(executor) {
        super((resolve, reject) => {
            // before
            return executor(resolve, reject);
        });
        // after
    }

    then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
        // before
        const returnValue = super.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
        // after
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

It contains these problems:

1/. It runs the code inside the promise before `await` calls.

```
$log('start...');

await task;
```

Output:

> foo
>
> start...

2/. It cannot be used with `await` multiple times

```
await task; // works
await task; // does nothing
await task; // does nothing

$log('done.'); // never logged
```

3/. It requires to run the content of the promise first, otherwise, throw error message:

> Promise resolve or reject function is not callable

```
super((resolve, reject) => {
    // this line would run the function
    // so, what's happened if I store it to "run"
    // and return a fake function?

    return executor(resolve, reject);
});
```

test:

```
let run;

super((resolve, reject) => {
    run = () => executor(resolve, reject);
     
    let foo = function () { };

    return foo(resolve, reject);
});

this.run = run;
```

and

```
then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
    this.run(); // works

    // Promise resolve or reject function is not callable
    const returnValue = super.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
    
    return returnValue;
}
```

And another point, I don't think it's a right way to use. But it should help a lot:

In the `then` method:

```
return Promise.resolve(this[__task__]['action']).then(args[0], args[1]);
```

same to:

```
return Promise.resolve(func).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
```

Everything I need in that line is:

I need a returned value and the value is a promise. Also, the promise contains a function, just contains, NOT runs it.

So, if I change `Promise.resolve` to:

```
// "new Promise" runs the function...
return new Promise(func).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
```

or

```
// infinite loop...
return new Task(func).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
```

it works wrong.

Addition point: In C#, there is no concept that `resolve` or `reject`. So, I think I can hack the code a bit.

That means: `Promise.resolve` doesn't mean `it's always resolved`.

You have any idea about this?

p/s: It took me a lot of time to complete, please don't close without a comment. Thank you!

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, you should not mix C# and JS. #1 You should have a snippet that has as little code as possible. #2 Not sure why you have a bunch of code with logging. #3 Regarding your "another point', we don't ask two questions in one at SO. Also, from your question, it doesn't look like you understand how await works in JS.

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks for your comment. #1 I think the code is still small if I remove the testing. It's just for "how to use it?". #2 I'm showing how the code can run with `await` multiple times (that's one of the differences). #3 I didn't find any answer about `Promise resolve or reject function is not callable` in SO, so, I think it's not duplicate.

Comment: This is now how promises work. A promise is an asynchronously available result *value*, it is not a runnable task. If you insist making your JS code look like C# (I cannot recommend it), do not let your Task extend Promise. You can keep it thenable so that it somehow works with `await`, but you should implement the rest yourself.

Comment: @Bergi Got it! I've got a small trouble with the name `Task`. Although everything looks like it works fine but it doesn't mean `how a task works`. Do you agree that it's easy to use? Have a great day. Thanks!